# Load File from root directory

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, visual-studio, file

I want to load my dic.xml file from the root folder , as now I am giving the full path in my application but i want a file loaded from the root directory.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\anu notes\FYP\LSC 1\LSC 1\LSC\LSC\dic.xml");
```

Comment: from the root directory? Did u mean the difference between absolute and relative path and u want to load it from your current application path or what?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
var rootFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
var xmlFilePath = rootFolder + @"\dic.xml";
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
```